# How can I filter out redundant results except one?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

| Type | Count | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 11-24 |
| 3 | 0 | 11-24 |
| 4 | 0 | 11-24 |
| 2 | 13 | 12-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 12-01 |
| 4 | 0 | 12-01 |
| 2 | 0 | 12-08 |
| 3 | 0 | 12-08 |
| 4 | 0 | 12-08 |

The table above has entries from three dates (11/24, 12/1, and 12/8). What I want to do is if the date group (say 11/24) has at least one row with a positive count, remove all rows with a 0 count. But if the date group (like 12/8) has all rows with a 0 count, then remove all but one of the rows. And ideally, the remaining 0 count row has a new type, like 5 for instance. For example, the desired output would be:

| Type | Count | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 11-24 |
| 2 | 13 | 12-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 12-01 |
| 5 | 0 | 12-08 |

Is this possible with KQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let T = datatable(Type:int, Count:int, Date:string)
[
   ,2 ,20 ,"11-24"
   ,3 ,0  ,"11-24"
   ,4 ,0  ,"11-24"
   ,2 ,13 ,"12-01"
   ,3 ,1  ,"12-01"
   ,4 ,0  ,"12-01"
   ,2 ,0  ,"12-08"
   ,3 ,0  ,"12-08"
   ,4 ,0  ,"12-08"
];
let max_type = toscalar(T | summarize max(Type));
union  (T 
        | where Count > 0
        )
      ,(T
        | summarize Count = max(Count) by Date 
        | where Count == 0
        | serialize Type = toint(max_type + row_number())
        )
```

| Type | Count | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 11-24 |
| 2 | 13 | 12-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 12-01 |
| 5 | 0 | 12-08 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WRQWrDMBBF9wbf4ZOVRBWwHC9KirtJjqBdKUFuRSuw5SLLpCk5fMcyiYVpJS2Gp/kz%20qPWBCjUeNeBdtMapi5fZm9dEDj0owtzeNTB7IfgrfvgefaSZwBESaeA2Ei5LavNzHYQBVas%20oORVu4mVm4LuWglVuyuTViZsMd134RVK/b6lGct%20e309ymQS7Id%20uFNt9ozhSuGseu0tz9myohz4Jwko7O9Aygllo3rivOn8WYeEZ5RLFf8FgqmUsFSfRbVsUuMOZpLHPG/Heo6bUHFjLe6nYqpmxH6J3Z39gDfn09u7BrjGefJ634BWk8tnvEBAAA=)